# I found a phrase in the Oxford dictionary: “my birthday seems to come round quicker each year”. Why is the word quicker used instead of more quickly?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I think adverb is needed here to quality “come round”. So why here we use “quicker”?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: "Quicker" *is* an adverb (as well as an adjective).